# How may I copy all images from different 12 folders to a single folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, glob, shutil

I am working with an `image dataset`. It has `12 different folders` with `12 different classes`. For this reason, I want to `reserve all images` in `a single directory` that is `all_im`. I am writing code on it but it only copies a total of `808 images`. But my main folder contains `more than 5000 images`. How may I `copy` all of the images from the `main folder` to a `new folder` in `Google-Colab`?

My full code:

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(101)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(101)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import tensorflow

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint

import os
import cv2

import imageio
import skimage
import skimage.io
import skimage.transform

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import itertools
import shutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

SAMPLE_SIZE = 250

# The images will all be resized to this size.
IMAGE_SIZE = 96

os.listdir('content/image_dataset')

folder_list = os.listdir('/content/image_dataset')

all_im_dir = 'all_im'
os.mkdir(all_im)

destination_path = "/content/all_images"
pattern = "/content/Weeds_dataset/*/*"  
for img in glob.glob(pattern):
    shutil.copy(img, destination_path)
```

Print function: `len(os.listdir('all_images'))`

Output: `808 images`

Expectation: the main folder contains `5300 pictures` but I am able to copy only `808 Images`.

Comment: Are you sure all files have unique names within the subdirectories? You're effectively flattening any hierarchy here.

Comment: Where does the output come from? I can't see any print function.

Comment: Dear mentor, in each and every folder the files have the same number i.e. 1 to 800, or 1 to 1000. Like this. That means all of the files in each folder has the same number

Comment: That sounds like you copied all 5300 images into one folder and overwrote the existing images. There are 808 distinct file names. You could add a counter into the last loop to verify it.

Comment: What should I have to do now? @ThomasSablik

Comment: You have to rename the images. You could add a counter to the last loop and use the counter to name the images.

Comment: I coped all 5300 files from Image_dataset in where 12 different folders exist and save them into the all_images folder.

Comment: Could You give me some instruction to write such code? @ThomasSablik

Comment: `counter = 1`, `counter += 1` and `shutil.copy(img, destination_path + '/' + str(counter))`

Comment: Should I write this code before writing the code about copy files? @ThomasSablik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224301/discussion-between-as-if-and-thomas-sablik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename the images. You could add a counter to the last loop and use the counter to name the images.

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(101)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(101)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import tensorflow

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint

import os
import cv2

import imageio
import skimage
import skimage.io
import skimage.transform

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import itertools
import shutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

SAMPLE_SIZE = 250

# The images will all be resized to this size.
IMAGE_SIZE = 96

os.listdir('content/image_dataset')

folder_list = os.listdir('/content/image_dataset')

all_im_dir = 'all_im'
os.mkdir(all_im)

destination_path = "/content/all_images/"
pattern = "/content/image_dataset/*/*"
counter = 0
for img in glob.glob(pattern):
    counter += 1
    shutil.copy(img, destination_path + str(counter) + img.split('.')[-1])
```